# Python: Why can't I assign new value to an array in this case?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, variable-assignment

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([['Height', 'Weight'],['165', '48'],['168', '50'],['173', '53']])
data[0,0] = data[0,0] + "_1"
```

**data[0,0]** is **'Height'**, and I want to replace it with **'Height_1'**. But the code above doesn't work. It returned the result as:

```
data[0,0]
```

> 'Height'

The **data[0,0]** element remained the same. And if I replace it directly without referring to itself, it still doesn't work.

```
data[0,0] = "Height" + "_1"
```

result:

```
data[0,0]
```

> 'Height'

But if I replace it with some characters other than **"Height"**, it works.

```
data[0,0] = "str" + "_1"
```

Result:

```
data[0,0]
```

> 'str_1'

I took this case to explain the problem I'm coming across. And in my work I have to refer to the array itself because I need to replace the elements which don't meet some requirements. Anyone have solutions on this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you should be mixing strings and ints together

Comment: @jamylak to be precise, OP is only using strings here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know, I meant that OP should not be including the column headers into the data, and numbers shouldnt be saved as strings

Comment: @jamylak I agree, but perhaps it is better to be specific in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your array is of `dtype('<U6')`

```
>>> data = np.array([['Height', 'Weight'],['165', '48'],['168', '50'],['173', '53']])
>>> data.dtype
dtype('<U6')
>>>
```

It will automatically truncate:

```
>>> data[0,0] = "123456789"
>>> data
array([['123456', 'Weight'],
       ['165', '48'],
       ['168', '50'],
       ['173', '53']], 
      dtype='<U6')
>>>
```

You can always specify your dtype as 'object' when you create your array, but this removes a lot of the speed benefits of `numpy` to begin with.

Alternatively, you can specify a longer string type:

```
>>> data
array([['Height', 'Weight'],
       ['165', '48'],
       ['168', '50'],
       ['173', '53']], 
      dtype='<U20')
>>> data[0,0]='Height_1'
>>> data
array([['Height_1', 'Weight'],
       ['165', '48'],
       ['168', '50'],
       ['173', '53']], 
      dtype='<U20')
>>>
```

But be careful, as if you set the limit too-long you will be wasting memory:

```
>>> data = np.array([['Height', 'Weight'],['165', '48'],['168', '50'],['173', '53'], ['42','88']], dtype='U20')
>>> data.nbytes
800
>>> data = np.array([['Height', 'Weight'],['165', '48'],['168', '50'],['173', '53'], ['42','88']], dtype='U6')
>>> data.nbytes
240
```

If you only need a limited amount of characters, consider using byte-strings (1/4th the memory requirement):

```
>>> data = np.array([['Height', 'Weight'],['165', '48'],['168', '50'],['173', '53'], ['42','88']], dtype='S20')
>>> data.nbytes
200
>>>
```

Comment: or specify a longer string dtype, e.g. U20

Answer (score 3):

specify an **object** type for your array, such as:

```
a = np.array([['Height', 'Weight'],['165', '48'],['168', '50'],['173', '53']],dtype=object)
```

Then, 
`a[0][0]+='_1'` will do the trick, you will get:

```
array([['Height_1', 'Weight'],
       ['165', '48'],
       ['168', '50'],
       ['173', '53']], dtype=object)
```